# How to have my cursor change to pointer when hovering over the area of a shape?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a triangle on my page and if the user hovers over it, it should change the cursor to a pointer. So far so good.

The triangle is made in CSS:

```css
#triangleShape {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 300px solid transparent;
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 400px solid rgb(18, 75, 35);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangleShape"></div>
```

So if the user hovers over this div, it changes the cursor but it should change the cursor only when the user is hover over the actual green triangle. I know this CSS reacts to the whole div, but is this possible what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider SVG to create the shape and you will have what you need:

```css
svg polygon{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg height="300" width="400">
  <polygon points="200,0 0,300 400,300" fill=green />
</svg>
```

Or consider `clip-path`:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a normal behaviour as the transparent border is a part of your `div`. The `cursor: pointer` will then react to the whole square.

You could use a child element (pseudo element or anchor tag) and play with `overflow` and `transforms`.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div::before {
  cursor: pointer;
  content: ' ';
  display:block;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(150px) translateY(150px)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below reference to get a better idea about CSS cursor Properties.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

That being said, you can use the following snippet to get the work done.

```css
.triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-up"></div>
```

Good luck!